# Why is my milliamp and microamp current reading so different?

Tags: multimeter

When I check the current in my circuit using milliamp I get around 2.54 milliAmp. When I use the microamp setting, I get 1844 microAmps which translates to around 1.84 milliAmp.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You might want to concentrate on your previous question first and add that information there instead of posting a new question. It all works together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meter will be using a different shunt resistor, so it will be altering the total resistance of the circuit and hence altering the current flowing through the circuit.